# How to deal with logic error with async?

Tags: javascript, async-await

As I use async in my work. I will send a ajax requst, and then receive.

I will write like this.

```
const API = {
  init() {
    this.initIndexData();
  },

  async initIndexData() {
    try {
      let data = await this.getData();
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  },

  getData() {
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      $.ajax({
        url: 'xx.json',
        success(res) {
          if (res.success) {
            resolve(res);
          } else {
            reject(res);
          }
        }
      })
    });
  }
}

API.init();
```

As I don't like wirte code with `try..catch`. Is there any solutions to deal with `reject` without using `try catch`.

I think I can always use `reolve` whenever what happens. Like this.

```
if (res.success) {
  resolve(res);
} else {
  reject(res);
}
...

let data = await this.getData();
if (data.success) {
  // do sth success logic
} else {
  // do sth error logic 
}
```

Above is a solution to deal with `reject` without `try catch`, but this code isn't semantic.

Comment: "*I don't like wirte code with `try..catch`*" - why?

Comment: @Bergi I think when I use try .. catch when I don't know what error is happen. But in the example I write, you can see what error is happen, so I think is not necessary to use try .. catch deal with this error.

Comment: Well, if you only want to catch the `!res.success` case, then maybe you just should `resolve` with `res` and put the condition where you want to handle that. Your promise would also reject (and the `catch` would trigger) in case of a network problem, a JSON syntax error or something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ordinary [`.catch` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) of promises:

```
async initIndexData() {
  let data = await this.getData().catch(e => {
    console.log(e);
  });
},
async getData() {
  const res = await $.ajax({
//            ^^^^^ much better than `new Promise`
//                  as it does not ignore the ajax error handler
        url: 'xx.json',
  });
  if (res.success) {
    return res;
  } else {
    throw res;
  }
}
```